# Is this correct for this expression?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

I have seen the expression the identity product in somewhere and I try to express it again as
 \begin{align}
        %
        \prod _{k=1}^K\left(1-x_{k}\right)=\sum _{k=1}^K
        \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\underbrace{\sum _{n_1=1}^K \ldots \sum
        _{n_k=1}^K}_{n_1\neq  n_2\neq \ldots \neq ~ n_k}
        \prod _{t=1}^k x_{n_t}
        %
    \end{align}
However, I am not sure if it is correct expression or not ?
Could you give me a hint ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good expression would be (don't forget $k=0$ !)
$$
\prod_{k=1}^K(1-x_k)=\sum_{k=0}^K(-1)^k\sum_{1\leq i_1<\ldots <i_k\leq K}x_{i_1}\ldots x_{i_k} = \sum_{k=0}^K\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{1\leq i_1\neq \ldots \neq i_k\leq K}x_{i_1}\ldots x_{i_k}.
$$
You can see it directly by developing the product and playing with permutations, or using the relation coefficients and roots of a polynomials using symmetric functions, namely plugging $z=1$ in 
$$
\prod_{i=1}^K(z-x_i)=\sum_{k=0}^Kz^{K-k}(-1)^k\sum_{1\leq i_1<\ldots <i_k\leq K}x_{i_1}\ldots x_{i_k}.
$$

Comment: downvote ? Did I do something wrong ?

Comment: Looks very spiffy to me, Student.