# Finite Jacobi triple product

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, products, euler-product

With regard to the post [Is this correct for this expression?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/175549/725141)

Could we obtain an expression  for the double finite product below?
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n\prod_{j=1}^k(1-x_{ij}),
$$
Where $0<x_{ij}<1\,\,\forall (i,j)$.

Comment: There is no difference, just consider the change of variable $z_{(i-1)\cdot k+j}=x_{i,j}$

Comment: What does it mean  $z_{(i-1)\cdot k+j}$? Then we get a single product?

Comment: Nothing, it is just a name for $x_{i,j}.$ Yes, then you get one product, but like $\prod _{s=1}^{nk}(1-z_s)$